# Wordpress style sheet validator error

Tags: wordpress

When I validate my page, I get this error:

```
Error Line 304, Column 160: Element link is missing required attribute property.              

…t-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css?f26ef4" type='text/css' media='all' />
Attributes for element link:
Global attributes
href
crossorigin 
rel
media
hreflang
type
sizes
Also, the title attribute has special semantics on this element.
```

Link to site: http://mmdf14m6dk19.keaweb.dk/

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<link>` isn't in the `<head>` of your document it's in the `<body>` - you need to move it.

Comment: hmm okay.. any idea how i find it in the theme i use ... i have looked in the footer.php.. but it's not there..

Comment: It's almost impossible for me to tell without having access to your theme, as most are set up differently. I'd assume it's in a `header` include.